# como dar acceso a un servidor linux por determinado tiempo

Tags: linux, ip

Quiero dar acceso a mi servidor linux por medio de IP pero con un temporalizador (ejemplo que la ip 190.53.53.53 pueda hacer conexion por 2 horas nada mas) que automaticamente el servidor de la baja a la ip.

Habra algun programa automatizado ya o alguien me oriente como empezar

Edit: encontre este comando pero es manual yo tendria que agregar la ip y borrarla
Comando agregar acesso: $ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.101.123 proto tcp to any port 8018
Comando Borrar acceso: $ sudo ufw delete allow from 192.168.101.123 proto tcp to any port 8018

yo necesito darle un tiempo de expiracion a la ip

Comment: Se me ocurre que hagas un pequeño script con los comandos y luego lo ejecutes mediante el crontab

Comment: Y eso seria en php?

Comment: Una opción que se me ocurre es el uso del módulo time de iptables, en la forma - - timestart 12:00 - - timestop 14:00. Por ejemplo a la hora de filtrar tu acceso mediante ssh.

Answer (score 4):

Tal como el comentario de Alexander, sólo debes agregar estos comandos a crontab. No necesariamente en un script. Puedes poner los dos comandos con las horas que quieres de inicio y fin. Ej.:

Para editar el crontab de root:

```
# sudo crontab -e
```

Agrega la una linea para dar acceso, la regla de tiempo es; minuto, hora, dia del mes, mes, dia de la semana. Esto separado por espacio y '*' para todos. Ej. para todos los días a las 8 en punto de la mañana:

```
0 8 * * * /usr/sbin/ufw allow from 192.168.101.123 proto tcp to any port 8018 > /dev/null
```

También agrega la linea para eliminar el acceso, dos horas después:

```
0 10 * * * /usr/sbin/ufw delete allow from 192.168.101.123 proto tcp to any port 8018 > /dev/null
```

Luego salva el archivo y listo.

Puedes probar cambiando el rango de tiempo a sólo 5 minutos y listando las reglas con:

```
# sudo ufw status
```

En caso que UFW esté deshabilidato:

```
# sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: y esto como soluciona el problema????

Comment: Excente Respuesta, lo felicito!

Comment: Es buena opcion pero eso seria para todos los dias a esa hora, pondre un ejemplo yo qiero que entren 2 horas diarias al vps o ip, pero el decidira las horas

Comment: Entonces podrías usar la regla de dar acceso que corra todos los días al inicio del día. Luego crear un pequeño script que corra cada minuto y guardar un pequeño log de cuando se conectan al servidor si es un servicio Web o con el comando `lastlog` para ver el último inicio de sesión si es SSH, con esto puedes correr la regla de bloquear el acceso luego de las dos horas de conectarse.

Comment: Ahora leo tu comentario, Mario. Mucho me temo, entonces, que la solución que te propuse más abajo no te valga.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenté más arriba, mediante netfilter puedes conseguir lo que buscas, definiendo un rango de horas del día en que se permita el acceso (no tengo claro que sea lo que deseas, o quieres tener acceso a cualquier hora, y que la sesión expire después de dos horas de conexión).

Suponiendo que quisieses acceder mediante SSH, mapearemos su puerto por defecto mediante estas dos reglas:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --source 190.53.53.53 -j ACCEPT -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 02:00


sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 22 --source 190.53.53.53 -j ACCEPT -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 02:00
```

Explico detenidamente la primera regla, y la segunda se dé por entendida:

-A INPUT : añade la regla siguiente a la cadena INPUT (paquetes entrantes).

-p tcp : para el protocolo tcp.

--dport 22 : en el puerto de destino 22 (el que usa SSH por defecto).

--source direccion.de.ip : desde el origen cuya ip es...

-j ACCEPT : proponemos aceptar todos los paquetes.

-m time : llamamos al módulo time para poder hacer uso de los dos siguientes parámetros.

--timestart 00:00 : permitimos el acceso desde las 00:00 horas hasta...:

--timestop 02:00

Y el resultado:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
ACCEPT     tcp  --  190.53.53.53         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 TIME from 00:00:00 to 02:00:00 UTC
ACCEPT     udp  --  190.53.53.53         0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:22 TIME from 00:00:00 to 02:00:00 UTC
```

Suerte.